# Create backup automatically using crontab

Tags: ubuntu, backup, cron

I am trying to make backup of mysql database autoatically using crontab but when I but the command directly int /etc/crontab file the backup created successfully

```
19 16 * * * root mysqldump -u root -prootroot -h192.168.4.5 radius  | gzip > /etc/freeradius/nh.sql.gz
```

the above command work nice but when I but this command in file and execute the file from crontab the database can not be created 
this is the content of /etc/freeradius/backup.sh

```
mysqldump -u root -prootroot -h192.168.4.5 radius | gzip > /etc/freeradius/nh.sql.gz
```

and this is the content of crontab file

```
46 16     * * *   root    /etc/freeradius/backup.sh
```

but there is no any thing happen even if the command is executed  as I saw in syslog file

Comment: I am betting you have a bug in your script or something, and since you have no MTA you aren't seeing the results.  Maybe send your output to a file temporarily.  `46 16     * * *   root    /etc/freeradius/backup.sh > /path/mylogfile`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a file `db_dump.sh` -> script to dump the contents of a database into separate files in the directory "/backups/"

```
#!/bin/bash

mysqldump -x --add-drop-table  --all-databases > /backups/mysqldb-`date +%F-%I%p`.sql

/usr/bin/mysql -e 'show databases' | /usr/bin/awk '{print $1}' | /bin/grep -v "^Database$" | /usr/bin/xargs -i{} /usr/bin/mysqldump --single-transaction --opt -Q -r /backups/`date +%F-%I%p`-{}.sql {}

gzip -q /backups/*.sql
```

Make sure that `db_dump.sh` is executable.

Add to crontab, in my case 10 p.m., daily:

```
crontab -e
```

and add:

```
0 22 * * * /db_dump.sh
```

For a full backup and nice explanation visit: https://github.com/zauberware/automated-server-backups

Answer (score 0):

Make your `backup.sh` into a proper shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash
mysqldump -u root -prootroot -h192.168.4.5 radius | | gzip > /etc/freeradius/nh.sql.gz
```

and don't forget to make it executable with

```
 chmod 700 /etc/freeradius/backup.sh
```

Comment: thank you for your replay but there is nothing happened

Comment: What do the log files say?

Comment: Aug 24 09:35:01 muhammad-VirtualBox CRON[1771]: (root) CMD (   /etc/freeradius/backup.txt )
Aug 24 09:35:01 muhammad-VirtualBox CRON[1770]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)

Comment: Not sure if it is the only issue but the double pipe (`... radius | | gzip > ...`) present in both the question, and quoted in this answer is probably not helping.

Comment: no no it is my typing wrong it is just 1 pipe in the file

Comment: See @Zoredache's comment to look into this further and edit your post to show us that output.